# Create a count on a Grafana Dashboard

Tags: grafana, promql

I am new the Grafana and I am creating a dashboard. I need to show the count of a metric. Below is the data generated for it:

[image]

I want to create a count of the **name** per unique deploymentId. For e.g. in the image above there are 2 deploymentId's 187 and 191. So, the count should show 2.

I have written the below query for it, but I am getting 0 as the result.

```
("count", rate(name{tenant=~"$Agencies"}[$__rate_interval]))
```

Note: Agencies is a filter at the top of the Dashboard. The count should be able to filter based on the change in the selection of Agencies.
Can I please get help on this?

Comment: Screenshot shows metrics for some time. Are you expecting count over that time, or just current count? Also, what query is used in the panel show on screenshot?

Comment: And finally, am I correct to assume that you simply want number of distinct deployments, and name has nothing to do with it? And if not, provide example of input and expected output.

Comment: @markalex: Yes, you are right to assume that I need the number of distinct deployments and name has nothing to do with it. I need the count over a time range provided by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate number of distinct label values you can use `count(count by(label) (...)` construct. (Strictly speaking inner aggregationcan be anything with  `by(label)` clause)

To calculate over time range selected for dashboard, and not the last 5 minutes (staleness window) we need to "stretch" values so they are included in calculation. It can be done with `last_over_time`.

Your final query will look like this:

```
count(count by(deploymentId) (last_over_time(name{tenant=~"$Agencies"}[$__range]))
```

Notice, it's not clear if you have metric named `name`. I assume that you do based on your attempt. If no - use any metric with labels `deploymentId` and `tenant`.